# BlackJack Java without arraylist

Tags: java, blackjack

I am not allowed to use ArrayLists , and I'm trying to make a BlackJack game in Java, but I can't add a new card to the player's hand when the player presses the games button "New card" i.e. hits. The player wants to hit, but I can't figure out how to add the card to the hand. I'm stuck when it comes to the method to hit. What can I do to make it work?

I want the card to be random and the player to be able to hit multiple times.

```js
 public static  void cardDraw () {
     
  for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
  cards[i] =1 +(int)(Math.random() * 9);
  
  cardsUsed++; 
  

 }
```

Full code (note: some parts are in swedish):

```js
// DENNA ÄR EJ KLAR. W.I.P. att byta arraylist<integer> metod till vanlig array


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;//random number generator
import java.util.ArrayList;//Array lists

class CardGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
 
 JLabel välkommenMessage = new JLabel ("Välkommen till BlackJack à la KG  ");
 static JTextArea spelRegler = new JTextArea("Klicka på 'Draw Card' för att få dina två första kort.\nOm kortsumman är under 16, fortsätt dra kort.\nKommer du över 21 förlorar du. ");
 
 JButton cardButton = new JButton ("Draw Card");
 JButton newCard = new JButton ("New Card");
 
    static JLabel kortText = new JLabel("");
 static JLabel blackJackSumma = new JLabel ("");
 static JLabel displayNewCard = new JLabel("");
 static JTextField kommando = new JTextField("", 20);
 
 JLabel stödlinjenText = new JLabel ("18+. Stödlinjen: 020-819 100"); //inte för att jag tror att detta spel kommer leda till något större beroende
 
 static int[] cards = new int [52];
    static int cardsUsed =0;
    
 
 public CardGame (){
  super("Card Game");
  setSize (270,250);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setVisible (true);
  Container contentArea = getContentPane();
  contentArea.setBackground(Color.white);
  FlowLayout flowManager = new FlowLayout();
  contentArea.setLayout(flowManager);
  spelRegler.setEditable(false);
  
  
  cardButton.addActionListener(this); 
  newCard.addActionListener(this);
  
  contentArea.add(välkommenMessage);
  contentArea.add(spelRegler);
  
  contentArea.add(cardButton);
  contentArea.add(kortText);
  contentArea.add(kommando); 
  
  contentArea.add(displayNewCard);
  contentArea.add(blackJackSumma);
        contentArea.add(newCard);
        
        contentArea.add(stödlinjenText); //längst ned för det utseendets skull
  setContentPane(contentArea);
  
 } 
 
  public static  void cardDraw () {
     
  for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
  cards[i] =1 +(int)(Math.random() * 9);
  
  cardsUsed++; 
  

 }
  

   public static int cardsSumma(){
    int sum = cards[3] = cards[0] + cards[1] + cards[2] ;
    
    return sum; 
   }
 
 
   public static void spelaKort(){
    
     int val = userCommando(); //användaren får välja att skriva 1 eller 2 beroende på vad användaren vill göra
        int total = cardsSumma();
        
     try{ 
  if (val == 1){ //om användaren skriver 1 dvs hit i fältet. Metoden har ropats på ovan
        cardDraw(); //drar ett nytt kort genom att kalla på metod
     displayNewCard.setText("Du har dragit kortet: "  );
     blackJackSumma.setText("Summa: "+ total);
 
 if (total == 21){ //i blackjack: vinner om man får 21
  blackJackSumma.setText("Du har vunnit!");
  return; 
  }
 else if (total> 21){ //över 21 = bust
  blackJackSumma.setText("BUSTED!");
  return;
 }
 else{                             //ingen condition behövs här
  blackJackSumma.setText("Summa: " + total);
  System.out.print(total);
       
  }
    }
    if (val == 2) { //om användaren väljer att avsluta, genom att input 2
     blackJackSumma.setText("Du har avslutat med summan: " + total);
     return; 
    }
     }catch (Exception e){
        spelRegler.setText("That was not a valid input");
     kortText.setText("That was not a valid input");
     blackJackSumma.setText("That was not a valid input");
     displayNewCard.setText("That was not a valid input");
    }
   }
   
    
    public static int userCommando(){ //kommando för att användaren ska välja strategi. sluta eller hit
     int val = 0;
   try{ 
    while(val != 1 && val != 2){
     val = Integer.parseInt(kommando.getText());
           }
       }   catch(Exception e){//fångar misstag om användaren e.g. skriver bokstäver
         spelRegler.setText("That was not a valid input");
         kortText.setText("That was not a valid input");
         blackJackSumma.setText("That was not a valid input");
         displayNewCard.setText("That was not a valid input");
           }
     return val;
   }
   

 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){ 
        
  if(event.getSource()==cardButton){
   cards[0] = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1; /* PLAYER GETS TWO CARDS - dessa är de två första korten som spelaren får
                                               *normalt sätt i blackjack = förberedelse
                                               */
            cards[1] = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
           
            
            int sum = cards[0] + cards[1];
      kortText.setText("Första två kort: " + cards[0] + ", " + cards[1]);
      blackJackSumma.setText("Summa: " + sum);
      
      
        if (cards[3]== 21){
         kortText.setText("DU vinner");
         return; 
        }
        else if (cards[3]< 21){
               spelRegler.setText("Skriv 1, tryck 'New Card' för ett till kort. Skriv 2 för att sluta spela"); 
        }
        else {
         spelRegler.setText("Bust");
        }
  }
        if (event.getSource()== newCard){
         spelaKort();
         cardsUsed++; 
         System.out.print(cardsUsed);
         
              }

     }
 }
      
public class Worksheet37a {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardGame Win = new CardGame();
  
 }

}
```

Comment: What does "I can't get my hit/add a new card when the player presses button to work" mean?

Comment: @JoeC Sorry, I'm a bit tired - I'll edit that. I meant: I can't add a new card to the player's hand when the player presses the games button "New card" i.e. hits. The player wants to hit, but I can't figure out how to add the card to the hand.

Comment: @CathyCathola, can you tell me at point "event.getSource()== newCard" you are getting its values true ?

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan No, it doesn't work with the newCard. The two cards the player gets in the beginning work fine (they are random, and are summed up together correctly). I can't get a new card to work... :/

Comment: At this point i.e "if (event.getSource()== newCard){
         spelaKort();
         cardsUsed++; 
         System.out.print(cardsUsed);
         
              }"
What is the value of variable val ?

Comment: @CathyCathola, In method spelaKort() do this, at line 3.
 System.out.println(val+"");
And mention, what is coming

Comment: @CathyCathola, your program is stuck  at while condition.
"while(val != 1 && val != 2){
     val = Integer.parseInt(kommando.getText());
           }"
if you put anything other then 1 or 2 it will stuck there because of your condition you need mention what logic you required here !

Comment: What does "not allowed" to use ArrayList mean?